# Funcion no funciona dentro de loops. Python 3

Tags: python

estoy haciendo una funcion que vea los divisores de un numero, luego los suma, y si son iguales al numero inicial, entonces devuelve el valor True.

Sin embargo esta funcion solo funciona afuera de un loop, ya que yo busco que este codigo me permita encontrar estos numeros que cumplan lo de arriba en cierto rango. Pero obtengo el valor False, en valores que deberian ser True.

Saque una foto y con flechas intento mostrarles cual es el problema que estoy mencionando:

[image: Aqui el problema]

Comment: Hay muchos problemas. El principal es que a nadie aquí le gusta ver código como imagen en vez de texto. El segundo problema es que `GetDivisor` emplea una variable global (`l`) que además no se vacía al principio de cada ejecución de la función, así acumulando más y más números. Otro problema es que hay una variable `np` con el mismo nombre que una función.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, tenia que meter l = [] dentro de la primera funcion